# jquery redirect user to specific page

Tags: php, jquery, redirect

I want the users to be redirected to specific user pages.
I have a table with 
username 
password 
redirect

I can't seem to write the code for redirect so that windows.location redirects to the links in the database for the specific user who logged in.

dataconnect.php

```
 <?PHP
    @mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
    or die("could not connect to mysql");
    @mysql_select_db("login")or die("no database");
    ?>
```

Index.php

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Animated Login</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".center").animate({
   opacity: 100.0,
   left: '+=800',
   height: 'toggle'
   }, 5000, function(){
});
$(".sign_b_btn").live("click",function() {
var u=$("#u").val();
var p=$("#p").val();
if(u==""){
$("#u").css("border-color","red");
$("#un").css("color","red");
$(".error").show().html("Please enter your username.");
$("#p").css("border-color","#606060");
$("#up").css("color","#333333");
}else if(p==""){
$("#u").css("border-color","#606060");
$("#un").css("color","#606060");
$(".error").show().html("Please enter your password.");
$("#p").css("border-color","red");
$("#up").css("color","red");
}else{
dataString = 'u=' + u + '&p=' + p;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "login_php.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){
if(html == "" ){
$(".error").show().html("The email or password you entered ois incorrect.");
$("#p,#u").css("border-color","red");
$("#up,#un").css("color","red");
}else if(html == "1"){
$(".error").fadeOut(1000);
$("#u").css("border-color","#606060");
$("#un").css("color","#333333");
$("#p").css("border-color","#606060");
$("#up").css("color","#333333");
$(".center").animate({
   opacity: 0.25,
   left: '+=900',
   height: 'toggle'
   }, 5000, function() {
$(".done").slideDown(200).html("Welcome "+u); 
setTimeout(function(){
var u=$("#u").val("");
var p=$("#p").val(""); 

window.location="home.php";
}, 5000);
});
}
}
});
}
}); 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="done"></div>
<div class="center">
<div class="title">Login</div>
<div class="error"></div>
<div class="input"><div class="left" id="un">Username:</div><div class="right">
<input type="text" class="log" id="u"></div><div class="c"></div></div>
<div class="input"><div class="left" id="up">Password:</div><div class="right">
<input type="password" class="log" id="p"></div><div class="c"></div></div>
<div class="sign_b_btn"><div class="sign_btn">Sign In</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

connect.php

```
<?PHP 
include('dataconnect.php');//Your connection to your database

//Get posted values from form
$u=$_POST['u'];
$p=$_POST['p'];

//Strip slashes
$u = stripslashes($u);
$p = stripslashes($p);

//Strip tags 
$u = strip_tags($u);
$p = strip_tags($p);

$p=md5($p);
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user ='$u' 
AND pass='$p'")or die(mysql_error());
$check = mysql_num_rows($check);
if($check !== "0"){
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user ='$u'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $user=$row['user'];
    session_register('user'); 
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
echo"1";
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: That does not help. My redirect links are in the database I want to redirect to the links in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jQuery you're posting to `login_php.php`.  Did you mean to post to `connect.php` instead?

Either way, what you'll probably want to do is just return the link you'd like to redirect to instead of 1 that way if the request is empty you'll continue to do what you're doing (throwing and error) and if it's not empty, you'll have a useful value.

Try updating `connect.php` to this:

```
<?PHP 
include('dataconnect.php');//Your connection to your database

//Get posted values from form
$u=$_POST['u'];
$p=$_POST['p'];

//Strip slashes
$u = stripslashes($u);
$p = stripslashes($p);

//Strip tags 
$u = strip_tags($u);
$p = strip_tags($p);

$p=md5($p);
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user ='$u' 
AND pass='$p'")or die(mysql_error());
$check = mysql_num_rows($check);
if($check !== "0"){
$results = mysql_query("SELECT user, redirect FROM user WHERE user ='$u'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $user=$row['user'];
    session_register('user'); 
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    echo $row['redirect'];
} 
}
?>
```

This assumes that your redirect column is in the users table.  If that's the case then it should return the user's redirect value to your jQuery ajax requester.  Then you can use it in the `else if` statement of your `Index.php`'s ajax callback function:

```
else if(html != ''){
var redirect_url = html;
$(".error").fadeOut(1000);
$("#u").css("border-color","#606060");
$("#un").css("color","#333333");
$("#p").css("border-color","#606060");
$("#up").css("color","#333333");
$(".center").animate({
   opacity: 0.25,
   left: '+=900',
   height: 'toggle'
   }, 5000, function() {
$(".done").slideDown(200).html("Welcome "+u); 
setTimeout(function(){
var u=$("#u").val("");
var p=$("#p").val(""); 

window.location=redirect_url;
}, 5000);
});
}
```

Aside from your question, I'd like to strongly recommend that you look into SQL injections.  As it stands your `connect.php` script is susceptible to SQL injections.  Basically, you need to escape your `$u` and `$p` variables.  Use something like `mysql_real_escape_string` to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here i editted my post try this............

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
$link=$row['redirect'];
} 
header('Location: "$link"');
```

Comment: I want to pull the links from the database. Its stored in the redirect column. I'm trying to setup a multiuser login like how facebook or flickr is.

Comment: This redirects directly as soon as I press the submit button. I want my jquery code to redirect esp. at this section  window.location="home.php";